# Wait until node-amqp has sent a message?

Tags: node.js, node-amqp

If I use the following code to send a message to RabbitMQ:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');
var connection = amqp.createConnection();
connection.on('ready', function() {
  connection.publish('foo', 'Hello');
  process.exit();
});
```

...then the message is never sent, and the process just quits. If I remove `process.exit()`, then the message is sent, but the process never quits.

How do I get **node-amqp** to tell me when it has sent a message?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, could you please close the question? @Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback in the [publish function](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#connectionpublishqueuename-body-options-callback). End the connection in the callback and exit.

```
connection.publish('foo', 'hello', function(){
   connection.end();
   process.exit();
});
```